# Given a A string , print Yes if it is a palindrome, print No otherwise

Tags: java, palindrome

I want to check if the user input is a palindrome or not. But this is not working as expected. Please help.

The code I tried:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        String A=sc.next();
        for (int i=0; i<A.length()/2; i++){
            if(A.charAt(i)==A.charAt(A.length()-i-1)) {
                System.out.println("Yes");
            } else {
                System.out.println("No");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your problem is that you already print out "yes" or "no" in the first iteration of the loop, when you will only have checked 1 letter position so far. This cannot work and you can only tell/print if something is a palindrome once you are done with checking all letters. (aka: After you are done with your loop)

Comment: try to improve your question - currently it is [unclear what you are asking](https://idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're printing "Yes" for every character that has the same character at the opposite end of the String and "No" if not. Modify your loop to return a boolean that tells whether the String is a palindrome or not and then print it at the end like so:

```
boolean isPalindrome = true;
for (int i=0; i<A.length()/2; i++){
    if(!A.charAt(i)==A.charAt(A.length()-i-1)){
    isPalindrome = false;            
    }
}

if(isPalindome){
    System.out.println("Yes");
} else {
    System.out.println("No");
}
```

Comment: But in your code you mention if(isPalindrome) it print yes but you mention isPalindrome=False. So it will print yes when palindrome is false

Comment: `isPalindrome` is initially true, If the palindrome condition, `A.charAt(i)==A.charAt(A.length()-i-1` is every violated, the String is not a palindrome, thus `isPalindrome` is set to false.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String A = sc.next();

    String reverse = new StringBuffer(A).reverse().toString();
    if (A.equals(reverse))
        System.out.println("Yes");
    else
        System.out.println("No");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 int end = A.length()-1;
    int i=0;
    boolean isPol = true;
    while (i<=end){
        if (A.charAt(i)!=A.charAt(end))
            isPol = false;
        i++;
        end--;
    }
    if (isPol == true) System.out.println("Yes");
    else System.out.println("No");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String A = sc.next();
        /* Enter your code here. Print output to STDOUT. */
        String reverse = "";
        int length = A.length();
        for (int i=length-1;i>=0;i--){
            reverse = reverse + A.charAt(i);
        }
        boolean ans = A.equals(reverse);
        if (ans) {
            System.out.println("Yes");
        } else {
            System.out.println("No");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String A = sc.next();
    
    boolean isPalindrome = false;
    int len = A.length();
    
    if(len > 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < len/2; i++) {
            if (A.charAt(i) == A.charAt(len-i-1)) {
                isPalindrome = true;    
            }else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }else if (len <= 1) {
        isPalindrome = true;
    }

    
    if (isPalindrome) {
        System.out.println("Yes");
    }else {
        System.out.println("No");
    }
    sc.close();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        String A=sc.nextLine();

        String temp="";
        for(int i=A.length()-1;i>=0;i--){
            temp = temp + A.charAt(i);
        }
        if(A.equals(temp)){
            System.out.println("Yes");
        }else{
            System.out.println("No");
        }
    }
}
```